# Facebook Login Api isnot working in Monaca

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, onsen-ui, monaca, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I'm trying to make an app with native facebook login with official api.

I follow this tutorial but it is not working.

http://onsen.io/blog/make-facebook-hybrid-mobile-app-with-monaca/

I cant build app when i try to upload with .zip file.

If i write only name "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" it is not included in build file.

What is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Developer plan or higher? You cannot import Cordova plugins with Basic Monaca plan.

Comment: Yes i have. When i try to upload via zip, i see plugin in panel but i cant build app.

Comment: i have a developer acc, so i cant sent ticket :(

Comment: send it anyway, I'll take care of it ;)